# MySQL OrderBY with string, number and null values

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a problem with sorting data in MySQL.

I have a varchar column, and in that column random texts are being saved, and I can't find a way to order correctly.

I have the following data:

```
| areas   | 
| ------- | 
| 1       | 
| 3       | 
| null    |
| area 01 |
| area 02 |
| 36548   |
| null    |
| area 20 |
| area 1  |
| area 4  |
```

I tried the following solution in OrderBy:

```
OrderBy
IF(column REGEXP '^[A-Z]', 
  CONCAT(LEFT(column, 1), 
  LPAD(SUBSTRING(column, 3), 20, '0')
), 
CONCAT('@', LPAD(column, 20, '0'))), 
LENGTH( column ), column ASC #Or DESC
```

But the result is wrong:

```
| areas   | 
| ------- | 
| null    | 
| null    |
| 36548   | 
| area 01 |
| area 02 |
| area 1  |
| area 20 | #Problem
| area 4  |
```

If I change the order to DESC it keeps the null data first and not last.

Request:
I would like to leave it in the correct order, respecting the alphanumeric order, regardless of the data entered.

Comment: Describe completely the ordering which you need.

Comment: It's at the end of the question.

Comment: `ORDER BY areas IS NULL, {another expressions}`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe with some logic applied in `order by`?

```
order by
  case 
    when areas is null then 'zzzz' 
    /* OTHER CONDITIONS */
    else areas
  end
```

Comment: The solution I tried above is applied to orderBy.

Comment: With your solution, it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

if you need that the null appears at the last, try this in mysql: **ORDER BY COALESCE(areas, 999999);**

```
SELECT areas
FROM Areas_table
ORDER BY COALESCE(areas, 999999);
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you need to sort by the order of the numbers and place the null value at the end? null values must be replaced, and the word "area" should be removed from the lines and padded with zeros on the left.

```
SELECT
    lpad(replace (coalesce(areas, lpad('',20,'Z')),'area ',''), 20, '0') as sorting_criteria,
    areas
  FROM sometable
  ORDER BY lpad(replace (coalesce(areas, lpad('',20,'Z')),'area ',''), 20, '0')
;
```

See [example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.5&fiddle=f023c1df309347f5ffed26d84e6437f4)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM sometable
  ORDER BY
  CASE 
       WHEN areas REGEXP '^[A-Z]'
       AND SUBSTRING_INDEX(areas,' ',-1) NOT LIKE '0%'
       THEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(areas,' ',-1)+0
       END, areas
```

Using `CASE` expression to do the first ordering by checking the starting value if it's alphabet using `REGEXP` (from your original attempt), and use `SUBSTRING_INDEX()` to check the second value separated by a space and return the second value as digit; by doing `+0`, the values of `1,4 & 20` will be returned in digit format instead of string. Other values will return `NULL` in that `CASE` operation. Then use the column as a second ordering condition.

The reason I separate `areas` for the `ORDER BY` condition instead of doing `ELSE areas` in the `CASE` expression is because if I do that, the result will be returned as string and will mess up the desired ordering.

[I borrowed fiddle from Sergey's answer](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.5&fiddle=660ec18bcde875e805ef007d3bb2c894)